# Qt QTextEdit and Page Break Line

Tags: qt

Is there such a class that provides a page break line? I've been looking all over the documentation and googling it, but I have not found any source about a line that tells the user where the page break is located. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to drill down a bit to find it..

[QTextEdit](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qtextedit.html) > [QTextDocument](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qtextdocument.html) > [QTextBlock](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qtextblock.html) > [QTextBlockFormat](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qtextblockformat.html) > [pageBreakPolicy](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qtextblockformat.html#pageBreakPolicy) > [QTextFormat::PageBreakFlags](http://QTextFormat%3a%3aPageBreakFlags).

Comment: Thanks Arnold for your help :). I have looked at that and it seems that it can automatically set a page break (leaving a blank space) which is great and I have used it. Any suggestions where I can separate the text page between the page breaks. ie a black or dotted line. or a way to actually cut the page.

Comment: I'm not sure. Sounds like a good candidate for a new question :) Make sure to mention what you already know about page breaks.

Comment: Thanks Arnold! Really appreciate it!